# Pandas fillna() not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to replace NaN values in my dataframe with means from the same row.

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.0,np.nan,5.0],
                   'B':[1.0,4.0,5.0],
                   'C':[1.0,1.0,4.0],
                   'D':[6.0,5.0,5.0],
                   'E':[1.0,1.0,4.0],
                   'F':[1.0,np.nan,4.0]})

sample_mean = sample_df.apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.dropna().values.tolist()) ,axis=1)
```

Produces:

```
0    1.833333
1    2.750000
2    4.500000
dtype: float64
```

But when I try to use `fillna()` to fill the missing dataframe values with values from the series, it doesn't seem to work.

```
sample_df.fillna(sample_mean, inplace=True)

    A     B     C     D     E     F
0   1.0   1.0   1.0   6.0   1.0   1.0
1   NaN   4.0   1.0   5.0   1.0   NaN
2   5.0   5.0   4.0   5.0   4.0   4.0
```

What I expect is:

```
    A     B     C     D     E     F
0   1.0   1.0   1.0   6.0   1.0   1.0
1   2.75  4.0   1.0   5.0   1.0   2.75
2   5.0   5.0   4.0   5.0   4.0   4.0
```

I've reviewed the other similar questions and can't seem to uncover the issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `pandas`

```
sample_df.T.fillna(sample_df.T.mean()).T
Out[1284]: 
      A    B    C    D    E     F
0  1.00  1.0  1.0  6.0  1.0  1.00
1  2.75  4.0  1.0  5.0  1.0  2.75
2  5.00  5.0  4.0  5.0  4.0  4.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way -

```
sample_df[:] = np.where(np.isnan(sample_df), sample_df.mean(1)[:,None], sample_df)
```

Sample output -

```
sample_df
Out[61]: 
      A    B    C    D    E     F
0  1.00  1.0  1.0  6.0  1.0  1.00
1  2.75  4.0  1.0  5.0  1.0  2.75
2  5.00  5.0  4.0  5.0  4.0  4.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Another pandas way:

```
>>> sample_df.where(pd.notnull(sample_df), sample_df.mean(axis=1), axis='rows')
      A    B    C    D    E     F
0  1.00  1.0  1.0  6.0  1.0  1.00
1  2.75  4.0  1.0  5.0  1.0  2.75
2  5.00  5.0  4.0  5.0  4.0  4.00
```

An `if` condition is `True` is in operation here:  Where elements of `pd.notnull(sample_df)` are `True` use the corresponding elements from `sample_df` else use the elements from `sample_df.mean(axis=1)` and perform this logic along `axis='rows'`.